# Vectorization for PCA in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, pca

I have a matrix A of 3D point coordinates, so the size of A is N by 3, where N is the number of points. I did a knnsearch on A for 20 neighbors and got a index matrix idN, which is N by 21. Then I want to calculate PCA for each point with its 20 neighbors. For example, the first point in matrix A, it would be

```
pca(A(idN(1,2:end),:))
```

And I want to calculate this for all the points. I can use a loop to do this but it will be very slow when the number of points is high. Is there a way I can calculate pca without using loop or at least a way to make this process faster?

Loop part of the code

```
idN = knnsearch(A,A,'k',21);
result = zeros(N,12);
for i = 1:N
    [coef,~,latent] =  pca(A(idN(i,2:end),:));
    result(i,1:9) = coef(:)';
    result(i,10:12) = latent';
end
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question showing your (loop) code in a [mcve]. We can't read your brain to see what code you've written so far, so we can't say how it can be improved.

Comment: Code added, thanks.

Comment: Since it is return of a built-in function, I thought there is no need to add that. Sorry about this, have added code for idN

Comment: I have explained this in my question, A is a matrix of 3D point coordinates. It is the input data, I can not show it here and these is not code for that. As  an example, we can use A=rand(N,3).

Comment: @sean. Unfortunately, it is very unlikely that you will be able to vectorize this.

Comment: It is very sad to know this, but thank you.